# How can I add a dependency on Java classes in a war file

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project that is packaged as a war, and I would like to use the Java classes from that package as a library dependency from a different project.

I tried just adding that dependency, but of course it is looking for a jar.
I also tried adding the maven-war-plugin, but that didn't seem to help:

```
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                        <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: Create a jar project to create that library, and make it a dependency of your war project, and of your current project.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by adding **modules** in your root **pom**

```
 <modules>
        <module>module-one</module>
        <module>module-two</module>
         ...
 </modules>
```

and in your child modules you should add that it has a **parent**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test.testy</groupId>
    <artifactId>nameOfArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>module-one</artifactId>
```